# synch and commit same file with 2 different repositories

Tags: cvs

We work in an eclipse java project connected to CVS repository. We have 2 different repositories, repo-A and repo-B. repo-B inherits repos-A.

What I need here is, whenever i do a change in a file in a single eclipse workspace(connected to repo A)
I should be able to synch the changes with both repos(A and B). Also should be able to commit the changes from single workspace into to different repositories.

Is there any solution?

Comment: what kind of CVS uses ? git svn others?

Comment: not svn/git, just CVS. The commands will be like CVS update(example).